# How do I find out, which columns has invalid value

Tags: c#, csvhelper, formatexception

I'm using CsvHelper to parse CSV files including type conversion, e.g. to DateTime.

When the cell value has invalid format, I get

```
while (CsvReader.Read())
{
    var record = CsvReader.GetRecord<TModel>();
    csvReader.GetRecord<MyModel>(); //throws following exception:

    // CsvHelper.ReaderException: 'An unexpected error occurred.'
    // Inner Exception
    //
    // FormatException: The string 'a' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '0'.
```

How do I find the cell's HeaderName or MyModel's property, that has failed to parse.

Comment: can't you handle the exception? or firstly get the value and the tryparse?

Comment: Of course, but how do I find out the property name?

Comment: You could use `GetField` instead of `GetRecord` to make the parsing more granular? E.g. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a try and in your catch you can get row and index using

```
int index = csvReader.Context.CurrentIndex; // zero based
int row = csvReader.Context.Row;          // 1 based
```

Then you can get your field using headers record

```
csvReader.Context.HeaderRecord[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

To add up on itdoesntwork, here is how I did it

```
catch (ReaderException e)
{                   
    string notification = $"The field { e.ReadingContext.HeaderRecord[e.ReadingContext.CurrentIndex] } has the invalid value { e.ReadingContext.Record[e.ReadingContext.CurrentIndex] }";                   
}
```